# How to create a model related to another to generate a list

Tags: python, django, model, logic

I am trying to create a todolist where users can create a list of tasks like "morning routine" and import them directly into my todo app.

**Models.py** Todo **and** TodoList

```
class Todo(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name="Nom de l'utilisateur")
    text = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name="Nom de la Todo")
    content = models.TextField(verbose_name="Description supplémentaire",null=True, blank=True)


class TodoList(models.Model):
    list = models.ForeignKey(Todo, on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name="Nom de l'utilisateur")
    text = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name="Nom de la Todo")
```

My todoApp is working but I cannot figure out how to link them and import the list from todo to TodoList

Thanks guys

Comment: Do you anticipate that the same Todo could appear in multiple TodoLists or will each Todo be assigned to exactly one TodoList?

Comment: Hi,
No ! One todo can be used in multiple todolist

Comment: Gotcha, I am not sure if you have looked into using a `ManyToMany` field rather than a `ForeignKey`, but it may be useful. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

In those docs, "Article" would be equivalent to your "TodoList" and "Publication" would be equivalent to your "Todo".

To add already created Todo tasks to your TodoList called "todolist1", you would be able to do things like:
`todolist1.todos.add(todo1, todo2)`
and query with:
`todolist1.todos.all()`

Answer (score 0):

If you added a ManyToManyField in place of the ForeignKey on TodoList's `list` attribute it may do what you need.

```
class Todo(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name="Nom de l'utilisateur")
    text = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name="Nom de la Todo")
    content = models.TextField(verbose_name="Description supplémentaire",null=True, blank=True)


class TodoList(models.Model):
    list = models.ManyToManyField(Todo, verbose_name="Nom de l'utilisateur")
    text = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name="Nom de la Todo")
```

Then in the logic of your app, you could do things like:

```
todolist1 = TodoList(text='Stuff to do before tonight')
toddolist1.save()

todo1 = Todo(author=author_obj, text="Brush teeth", content="Remember to floss")
todo1.save()
todo2 = Todo(author=author_obj, text="Comb hair", content="Use water")
todo2.save()

todolist1.todos.add(todo1, todo2)
```

Then you would get the list by doing:

```
todolist1.todos.all()
```

reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/ where `Article` in that example is equivalent to `TodoList`, and `Publication` is equivalent to `Todo`.

EDIT:
Removing an item from the TodoList would look like this:

```
todolist1.todos.remove(todo1)
```

`.remove()` won't delete a todo entirely, so `todo1` would still appear in the other todolists. To totally remove a todo from all todolists, you'd do something like.

```
todo1.delete()
```